# Using a self-join for a min value based off of an existing SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is very similar to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893114/minimum-value-mysql-query) and apparently a [common issue](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) in learning SQL.  At it's essense, I am trying to find a min() value using an existing table field.  The typical solution is to make a sub-query that is somewhat self referential. I have copied this code from my example above:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select min(A) A, id
  from yourtable
  group by id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.A = t2.A
```

In my example, however, I have a bunch of other conditions on my SQL query, such that, using the sub-query listed in the example will not work.  Said another way, I have an existing query that has a lot of different arguments that I need to preserve and use to get my appropriate query results.  I need to attach some new code that will effectually do this:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select min(A) A, id
  from *my existing query results*
  group by id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.A = t2.A
```

If I were to do what is listed in the first example I would be selecting a min value that doesn't exist in the result based off of the other conditions that already exist in the query.

If you're interested here is the existing query is linked below. It is a query generated by the Views module in Drupal 7 using the uc_catalog view.  I am then using `hook_views_query_alter()` to make my changes.  I am using a MYSQL database.

---

Edit: Perhaps a better description of what I'm trying to do is to attach a Groupwise Min task to an existing query and copy over it's WHERE condition to use inside the Groupwise task.  Can you show me how to do [this in this query](http://pastebin.com/G6DM1r8Q)?

Comment: Let me point out, that `select min(A) A, id FROM ... GROUP BY id` is illegal in most SQL implementations, since `A` is neither aggregated nor listed in the GROUP-BY list.  While MySql table extensions would allow such syntax, the result will be unpredictable.

Comment: @PM `A` is an alias for an aggregated result. It's just fine and dandy.

Comment: @Strawberry - Right. Should've noticed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (my existing query) t1
inner join
(
  select min(A) A, id
  from (my existing query)x
  group by id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.A = t2.A
```

Comment: I think I'm asking the question the wrong way.  That code snippet is an abstraction of what I'm trying to accomplish.  I personally feel that the solution will come from some kind of `WHERE existing_query.id = (SELECT id FROM table HAVING A = min(A)`

Comment: Well, I'm always eager to learn novel techniques... but if it doesn't work out, consider describing a less abstracted problem.

Comment: When my vocabulary catches up with my work my questions will be less abstracted -- I assure you!  I have copied the specific example and two things I've tried into my Pastebin http://pastebin.com/G6DM1r8Q

Comment: While your second attempt is vastly superior to the first, it's still too far off to easily kick into shape. I think you should start again, gradually building up complexity, and being very explicit about which columns you actually need returned, and definitely avoiding IN(SELECT...)!

Comment: I get what your saying.  The issue is that I can't rewrite the query only modify it as it is apart of a larger framework (specifically Drupal 7 Views)

Comment: ? Sorry, I don't follow - but then again I don't know anything about Drupal :-(

Comment: Basically drupal has preconstructed this query to browse my catalog so i'm very much stuck with it.  I can add WHERE and JOIN expressions to it, but I can't easily rewrite it.  Though 'easy' is of course a relative term.